# How to send multiple HTTP requests from the same service in Java?

Tags: java, http, jax-rs

Java noob here. I'm trying to develop a web service as per the following diagram.

[image]

1. When a POST request is sent to the REST server, with certain values, the values (being read from a list, in a loop) get inserted in a table (new row with an id). Server returns HTTP 202 Accepted.
2. To ensure that the resource(with id from 1) is created, a GET request is issued that returns the POJO as Json.
3. Finally a PATCH request is sent to update a certain column.

I have written a service class that does all three tasks when each API is called individually. I need to implement something that would automatically execute steps 2 and 3 when a POST request is sent to the server. Here's my code so far.

```
@Path("attachments")
public class FilesService {
private TiedostoService tiedostoService;
private AttachmentService attachmentService;    

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response listAttachmentsAsJson(@PathParam("id") Integer attachmentId) throws Exception {
    attachmentService = new AttachmentService();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
    Attachment attachment = attachmentService.getAttachment(attachmentId);
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(attachment.toString());
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(jsonString).build();
}

@PATCH
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response patchAttachments(@PathParam("id") Integer attachmentId) throws Exception {
    attachmentService = new AttachmentService();
    Integer update = attachmentService.update(attachmentId);
    String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(update);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.ACCEPTED).entity(jsonString).build();
}

@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response migrateToMinio(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) throws Exception {
    Response response;
    List<String> responseList = new ArrayList<>();
    tiedostoService = new TiedostoService();
    attachmentService = new AttachmentService();
    List<Tiedosto> tiedostoList = tiedostoService.getAllFiles();
    String responseString = null;
    int i = 1;
    for (Tiedosto tiedosto : tiedostoList) {
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.setCustomerId(tiedosto.getCustomerId());
        attachment.setSize(tiedosto.getFileSize());
        Integer id = attachmentService.createNew(attachment);
        if (id == 1) {
            UriBuilder builder = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder();
            builder.path(Integer.toString(i));
            response = Response.created(builder.build()).build();
            System.out.println(response);
            responseString = response.toString();
        }
        responseList.add(responseString);
        i++;
    }
    String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(responseList);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(jsonString).build();
}
```

}

when I test the individual endpoints with curl or postman, they work as expected, but I got stuck on how to execute GET and PATCH automatically after POST. I'd really appreciate some advice/suggestions/help.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. POST sends some data and PATCH sends other data. You can't do both the POST and PATCH with only the data for the POST.

Comment: Besides, if you want a request to do other things than another request, then you need to define a new endpoint for the new kind of request. This new endpoint can totally call the same services as the other existing endpoints were already calling.

Comment: @kumesana I skipped a small detail. after POST is issued, a new row is created and after that BLOB data is uploaded to a file server. After a successful upload, the upload flag is set to 1 and then PATCH is called. So, after each POST request, I need to make sure that resource is created with GET and updated with PATCH.

Comment: Then make sure to call all of them. What else?

Comment: @kumesana, so in POST method, can I just call listAttachmentsAsJson() after new row is created and patchAttachments() after the file is uploaded?

Comment: It's imaginable, but I'd suggest deleting listAttachmentsAsJson() and patchAttachements(), and just put everything they were doing in the POST method.

Comment: @kumesana Actually, I already have a version running the way you suggested. I just wanted to see if, in this context, whether I could call GET and PATCH as a part of POST execution.

Comment: It can possibly mess some stuff provided by your REST framework, in case it defines AOP elements on your class FilesService. Generally, methods defining endpoints are not meant to call each other, and if AOP is used as I said it will be defeated. So, not the best of ideas. But in general, it may work.

Comment: @kumesana Thank you very much for your time and explanation.